# Is "didn't be" correct English?

Tags: word-usage

Is "didn't be" or "did not be" grammatical?

For example, "He didn't be aggressive."

Comment: Auxiliary _do_ (or _does_ or _did_) **only** occurs when there is no other auxiliary verb in a clause, and some rule (like question formation or negative contraction) requires an auxiliary verb. But _be_ is always an auxiliary verb, so it never co-occurs with _do_.

Answer (score 0):

It is not used in standard Englishes, as far as I know; but it does occur in some dialects, for example Irish English.